# Is resolving promise necessary after sending response to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to call an asynchronous `function` after sending the response to the client.

```
res.json({});
someAsyncFunction(); //no await for this function
```

Would that be a bad thing to run that function without awaiting it's promise? Is it changing anything?

Comment: If you don't need to wait for the result, I don't see a reason to await its response

Comment: `await` makes the caller code wait for the result to become available; it's equivalent to attaching a `.then` callback. If that callback is empty anyway because there's nothing to do, then it makes no sense.

Comment: Keep in mind that not awaiting the result of the operation also ignores failures of the operation.  The "fire and forget" approach truly does mean "forget", insomuch as explicitly not caring if the operation fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By itself, no. Awaiting makes sense if and only if you might want to do something at the time when the promise is fulfilled. If there is no imaginable case when you would have any use of doing anything at the point the promise is fulfilled, then it is sub-optimal to await and therefore slowing down the process. Yet, if you are able to have a `.then()` which is a non-blocker, by contrast to `await`, so only use `await` if your code cannot continue reasonably without the fulfillment.

So, there are three cases:

- case 1: there is nothing to be waiting for. Then don't `await`.
- case 2: there is something you might want to do when the promise is fulfilled, but you can let the code perform normally before that. Then don't `await`, use `.then()` instead
- case 3: your code needs the fulfillment ASAP: Then `await`